# How do I get jboss to display log.debug messages?

Tags: java, jboss, log4j

**myController.java**

```
 private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(myController.class
  .getName());
@GET
  @Path("/testDebug")
  public String testDebug(@Context final ServletContext context)
  {
    log.error("This is an error message");
    log.debug("This is a debug message");
    log.fatal("This is fatal message");
    log.warn("This is a warn message");
    log.info("This is a info message");

    return "Test Page.  Debug Mode is on =" + log.isDebugEnabled();
  }
```

**jboss-log4j.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<!-- ===================================================================== -->
<!--                                                                       -->
<!--  Log4j Configuration                                                  -->
<!--                                                                       -->
<!-- ===================================================================== -->

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="false">

   <!-- ================================= -->
   <!-- Preserve messages in a local file -->
   <!-- ================================= -->

   <!-- A time/date based rolling appender -->
   <appender name="FILE" class="org.jboss.logging.appender.DailyRollingFileAppender">
      <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
      <param name="File" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/server.log"/>
      <param name="Append" value="false"/>

      <!-- Rollover at midnight each day -->
      <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>

      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <!-- The default pattern: Date Priority [Category] Message\n -->
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] %m%n"/>

          -->
      </layout>
   </appender>

   <!-- ============================== -->
   <!-- Append messages to the console -->
   <!-- ============================== -->

   <appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
      <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
      <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
      <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG"/>

      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <!-- The default pattern: Date Priority [Category] Message\n -->
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"/>
      </layout>
   </appender>


   <!-- ================ -->
   <!-- Limit categories -->
   <!-- ================ -->

   <!-- Limit the org.apache category to INFO as its DEBUG is verbose -->
   <category name="org.apache">
      <priority value="INFO"/>
   </category>

   <!-- Limit the org.jboss.serial (jboss-serialization) to INFO as its DEBUG is verbose -->
   <category name="org.jboss.serial">
      <priority value="INFO"/>
   </category>

   <!-- Limit the org.jgroups category to WARN as its INFO is verbose -->
   <category name="org.jgroups">
      <priority value="WARN"/>
   </category>

   <!-- Limit the jacorb category to WARN as its INFO is verbose -->
   <category name="jacorb">
      <priority value="WARN"/>
   </category>

   <!-- Limit JBoss categories -->
   <category name="org.jboss">
      <priority value="INFO"/>
      <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
   </category>



   <!-- Limit the JSR77 categories -->
   <category name="org.jboss.management">
      <priority value="INFO"/>
   </category>

   <!-- This is is the package to myController.java -->
   <category name="com.myPackage.src">
      <priority value="DEBUG"/>
   </category>

   <!-- ======================= -->
   <!-- Setup the Root category -->
   <!-- ======================= -->

   <root>
      <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
      <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
   </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

**Desired Result**

when path `/testDebug` is hit get the message: "This is a debug message"

**Problem:**

I get all message to display **except** debug

```
10:29:49,440 INFO  [STDOUT] 10:29:49,440 ERROR [myController] This is an error message
10:29:49,440 INFO  [STDOUT] 10:29:49,440 FATAL [myController] This is fatal message
10:29:49,440 INFO  [STDOUT] 10:29:49,440 WARN  [myController] This is a warn message
10:29:49,440 INFO  [STDOUT] 10:29:49,440 INFO  [myController] This is a info message
```

Why cant I get debug message to display?

Comment: which pacakge is your class myController in

Comment: @SurajChandran the location is com.myPackage.src.myController.java

Answer (score 5):

Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22044656/logging-with-debug-level-in-jboss-7-1-1?rq=1) for updated information on seeing debug logging with Jboss 7.1.1+.

Some points:

1. Your class `myController` uses the logging as expected. (*Another answer claims that you incorrectly instantiated your logger; not true.*)
2. Remove the log4j.xml (or logback.xml etc) configuration file from your project (i.e., from `main/resources/META-INF`)
3. In your `pom.xml`, make sure that your `slf4j` dependency has a scope of **provided** (Jboss will provide this). Further, do not include the log4j (or logback etc) implementation dependencies. For example, here's what your logging dependency section may look like:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
       <version>1.7.7</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
   ```
4. Make sure that you have a **logger** entry for your package in your `standalone/configuration/standalone.xml` file.

   ```
   <logger category="com.myPackage.src">
        <level name="DEBUG"/>
   </logger>
   ```
5. Make sure that **console-handler** and **periodic-rotating-file-handler** handlers have a level of DEBUG. (By default, they are INFO. They will need to be DEBUG or else your debug statements will be ignored.)

*Note, there is a CLI that allows you to update the logging. I do mine manually but it's probably wise to use the CLI.*

Here's an abbreviated version of what your `standalone.xml` logging portion could look like:

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:2.0">
        <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
        </console-handler>
        <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
            <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
            <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
            <append value="true"/>
        </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
        <logger category="com.myPackage.src">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
        </logger>
        <root-logger>
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                <handler name="FILE"/>
            </handlers>
        </root-logger>
        <formatter name="PATTERN">
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
        </formatter>
        <formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
        </formatter>
    </subsystem>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try doing so:

```
<category name="com.myPackage.src">
      <priority value="DEBUG"/>
   </category>
```

Comment: I added that to my jboss-log4j.xml. Still not working. I am still only getting the other messages and not the debug message. I added your feedback to the initial question

Answer (score 0):

Your category is defined incorrectly. When you instantiate your logger you're using [`Class.getName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName%28%29) which returns the fully qualified class name. You define your logger category with only the package name which means debugging is not turned on for the category `com.myPackage.src.myController`.

You need to either change the way you instantiate your logger

```
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(myController.class.getPackage().getName());
```

or change your category definition

```
<category name="com.myPackage.src.myController">
  <priority value="DEBUG"/>
</category>
```

On a side not, packages should not have uppercase characters and class names should always begin with an uppercase letter.

Answer (score -1):

```
Detailed information could be found at: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Logging+Configuration
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.0">
   <console-handler name="CONSOLE" autoflush="true">
       <level name="DEBUG"/>
       <formatter>
           <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
       </formatter>
   </console-handler>
   <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
       <formatter>
           <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
       </formatter>
       <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
       <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
   </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
   <logger category="com.arjuna">
       <level name="WARN"/>
   </logger>
   [...]
   <root-logger>
       <level name="DEBUG"/>
       <handlers>
           <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
           <handler name="FILE"/>
       </handlers>
   </root-logger>
</subsystem>
```

1.the changes can be made in standalone.xml
2.the above solution is to show how to see the debug messages of logs in jboss
this will solve the above problem

Comment: Hello Uday do edit your question and specify what you are trying to do. What is the problem that you are facing and what have you tried so far.

Comment: While this answer may contain the necessary information to solve the problem, it is not clear how it does so. Please edit and explain how your answer solves the OP's question.